# Not rendering Rails 4 partial correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I've upgraded a Rails 3 app to 4 and I'm trying to render some really simple partial thats not working correctly.

I'm using HAML and I have a layouts folder with a application.html.haml file inside. Within this file I call several partials that make up the template for the entire page. these partials reside in a application folder. For instance, I call:

`= render "chromeframe"`

which works perfectly. However, below this I have:

`= render "header"

which contains a lot of haml html code for the header of the page. My problem is this isn't getting rendered correctly and all I'm getting from that call is"
`<header id="header">
   <h1>Dummy</h1>
 </header>`

Still fairly new to Rails but I had this working perfectly in Rails 3 so I'm totally thrown by this problem. Any suggestions, I'm sure it's staring me in the face.

Thanks

Comment: looks like you have a dummy `_header.html.xxx` or `header.html.xxx` anywhere in your views, that is found by `render`. Doesn't have to be a haml file. Can you find something like that in your views?

Comment: I think you might be right but I can't find it anywhere. I've deleted _header.html.haml and I still see the <h1>dummy</h1> text. But I don't see it in my views anywhere. Is there anywhere else it might be hiding out that you know about? I'm also having the same problem with my footer.

Comment: look at your `deveopment.log`. It should say `Rendered ...header... (xx ms). It tells you, where the partial is found.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a dummy `_header.html.xxx` or `header.html.xxx` anywhere in your views, that is found by render. It doesn't have to be a haml file.

Look at your `deveopment.log`. It should say `Rendered ...header... (xx ms)`.
It tells you, where the partial is found.